# JavaFX TableView getItems().remove(i) does not work - why

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a situation where I'd like to delete all rows from a TableView. So I did the following code inside a button's setOnAction lambda expression. But this code doesn't work for me. None of the tableView's rows are deleted.

```
for (int i = data.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tableView.getItems().remove(i);  
}
```

where data is an FXCollections.observableArrayList with my class and tableView is an instance of TableView.

However, I am able to successfully delete a selected row from the same tableView. I did it using the following code from a ContextMenu's MenuItem's setOnAction handle function. Must be something simple I have missed.

```
theSelectedObject = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if (theSelectedObject != null) {
    int row = data.indexOf(theSelectedObject);
    data.remove(row);
}
```

So, why doesn't the first approach work? What am I missing?

Comment: This was because the data instance variable was recreated a second time without me knowing it. So the first case was operating on the expected data list and the second operation was operating on the newly created instance.

Comment: I just want to point out that there is a method call clear() you can call to remove all the data. tableview.getItem().clear().

Comment: There is probably something in the context of what you are doing which causes it not to work as you expect.  Please supply an [mcve], e.g. a complete, minimal program which could be copy and pasted to compile and run without modification to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm wondering why you write `data.size()` rather than `tableView.getItems().size()`?  Perhaps you are operating on different lists and that is the cause of your issue?.

Comment: As a debugging hint, if there is some exception being thrown in the lambda expression, you could surround the call with a try/catch and output the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This problem was resolved. It was because the code created two different lists and the delete was operating on the wrong list.

When the list is bound to the table view, I think I can simply work on the data model instead of the TableView so the change mechanism will take care of the updates.

Thanks so much for the useful comments!